# angular2 component communication using router outlet

Tags: angular, components

The below solution is not working for angular router.when I'm calling a method it is calling a service method successfully but parent i.e.Employer Component somethingChangedHandler() is not getting executed.

```
    @Component({
    selector: 'w2',  
     templateUrl: '../../html/views/w2old.html',
     providers:[ListReloadService]
     })

    export class W2Component implements OnInit {

      constructor(private _httpService:HttpService,
   private _router : Router,
     private _activatedRoute :ActivatedRoute,
     private _listReloadService:ListReloadService){

     }

    submitW2()
      {
        this._listReloadService.emitEvent(false); 
       //calling parent somethingChangedHandler()
     } 

    }

    **MySevice**

    @Injectable()
    export class ListReloadService {
    @Output()
     public somethingChanged: EventEmitter<boolean>;

     constructor(private _http: Http){
        this.somethingChanged = new EventEmitter();
     }

     public emitEvent(val: boolean){
        console.log("hello");
        this.somethingChanged.emit(val);
     }
    }

    **parent component**

     @Component({
        selector: 'employerhome',  
       templateUrl: '../../html/views/employerhome.html',
      providers:[ListReloadService]
      })

     export class EmployerHomeComponent  
      {
       constructor(private httpService:HttpService, private        listReloadService : ListReloadService){

         this.listReloadService.somethingChanged
         .subscribe(data=>this.somethingChangedHandler(data));
    }

   private somethingChangedHandler(someVal)
      {
       console.log("hello hi"); 
       }
    }
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: You need to provide the service on the component that contains the `<router-outlet>`, an ancestor of this component or `@NgModule()`. The link I posted before shows a quite similar example, just that the child component is not added by the router.

Comment: `ListReloadService` should be provided in `HomeComponent` or `AppComponent` or `@NgModule`, depending on which component should participate on the communication.

Comment: i have tried above solution but ,its not working for me . i am sharing my updated code

Comment: @Component({
  selector: 'w2',  
  templateUrl: '../../html/views/w2old.html',
  providers:[ListReloadService]
})

export class W2Component implements OnInit {
  w2:W2=new W2();
  private w2Id :number;

  constructor(private _httpService:HttpService,
  private _router : Router,
  private _activatedRoute :ActivatedRoute,
  private _listReloadService:ListReloadService){

  }

  submitW2()
  {
   this._listReloadService.emitEvent(false); //calling parent
  } 


}

Comment: i have shared my code please see what is the problem in my code.

Comment: resolved issue by adding my service in module level so the both component can share a single instance of service. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a service, example:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HiService {

   sayHi() {
      console.log("Hi!")
   }
```

}

inject in you AppComponent:

```
...
providers: [HiService]
...
```

use it in your components:

```
constructor(private hi: HiService) {
     console.log("constructor")
 }
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hi.sayHi()
}
```